# In R, how to add a column to a data frame based on the contents of the first column?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, pattern-matching, substr

I have a data frame of just one column that looks like this:

```
>df

     Sample_Name
1    GW16F1_A-1
2    GW16F1_A-10
3    GW16F1_A-12
4    GW16F2_A-2
5    GW16F2_A-3
6    GW16F2_A-5
7    GW16V1_A-6
8    GW16V1_A-7
9    GW16V2_A-8
10   GW16V2_A-9
```

I want to append a second column to this data frame based on the contents of the Sample_Name column, so the output would look like this:

```
>df
     SampleName   SampleGroup
1    GW16F1_A-1   F1
2    GW16F1_A-10  F1
3    GW16F1_A-12  F1
4    GW16F2_A-2   F2
5    GW16F2_A-3   F2
6    GW16F2_A-5   F2
7    GW16V1_A-6   V1
8    GW16V1_A-7   V1
9    GW16V2_A-8   V2
10   GW16V2_A-9   V2
```

Is there a function that will read through the contents of a column and output a new vector based on it?

Comment: This looks like a simple `substr` would work. No need for regex.

Comment: Could there be more digits than what you show in the sample, like in F13?

Comment: Not in this particular dataset, but I'd be curious to know the workaround to this based on @AnandaMahto 's answer.

Comment: @PinkSharpie, It depends on how much you can generalize the pattern in your dataset. For instance, can you generalize it to a sequence of "V or F followed by a certain number of digits and then an underscore"? If that's the generalization, `regex` would actually be better than `substr`.

Comment: I'm not an expert with `regex` so, I prefer the simpler courses of action when they are available.

Comment: As an example, `gsub(".*([VF][0-9]+)_.*", "\\1", df$Sample_Name)`....

Comment: Thank you! I am sure that will show up sooner or later :)

Comment: And it's shown up -- sooner than later! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`substr` should be sufficient for this, given your sample input.

Try:

```
> transform(df, sampleGroup = substr(df$Sample_Name, 5, 6))
   Sample_Name sampleGroup
1   GW16F1_A-1          F1
2  GW16F1_A-10          F1
3  GW16F1_A-12          F1
4   GW16F2_A-2          F2
5   GW16F2_A-3          F2
6   GW16F2_A-5          F2
7   GW16V1_A-6          V1
8   GW16V1_A-7          V1
9   GW16V2_A-8          V2
10  GW16V2_A-9          V2
```

Comment: Thank you! That is awesome. Accepting answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub` function also.

```
df$sampleGroup <- sub("^.*(..)_A.*", "\\1", df$Sample_Name)
```